# getting cellular network status via ADB shell

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to check via ADB if the phone is connected to a cellular network?

I had a look at [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#EXTRA_EXTRA_INFO), but it is for android application development.

Comment: i think you cant do that. but you can enable and disable mobile data

Comment: so there is no way I could determine from ADB shell if my phone is connected to a cellular network? is there anything I could do with radiooptions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certainly using the command from shell :

```
dumpsys telephony.registry
```

or directly from adb :

```
adb shell dumpsys telephony.registry
```

The values of **mServiceState** or **mDataConnectionState** will help you.
I tried in Plane mode mServiceState=3 / mDataConnectionState=0 and connected to the cellular network : mServiceState=0 / mDataConnectionState=2

PS: I'm using an Android 4.4 phone.

Comment: This works for LTE, but is there any way to get it working for HSPA?

Answer (score 7):

To add to Siri's answer, here are the values of **mServiceState**:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/ServiceState.html

> ```
> public static final int STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY
> ```
>
> Added in API level 1 The phone is registered and locked. Only
>   emergency numbers are allowed.
>
> Constant Value: `2 (0x00000002)`
>
> ```
> public static final int STATE_IN_SERVICE
> ```
>
> Added in API level 1 Normal operation condition, the phone is
>   registered with an operator either in home network or in roaming.
>
> Constant Value: `0 (0x00000000)`
>
> ```
> public static final int STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE
> ```
>
> Added in API level 1 Phone is not registered with any operator, the
>   phone can be currently searching a new operator to register to, or not
>   searching to registration at all, or registration is denied, or radio
>   signal is not available.
>
> Constant Value: `1 (0x00000001)`
>
> ```
> public static final int STATE_POWER_OFF
> ```
>
> Added in API level 1 Radio of telephony is explicitly powered off.
>
> Constant Value: `3 (0x00000003)`

And here are the values of **mDataConnectionState**:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#TelephonyManager.0DATA_UNKNOWN

> Data connection state: Unknown. Used before we know the state.
>
> ```
> public static final int DATA_UNKNOWN        = -1;
> ```
>
> Data connection state: Disconnected. IP traffic not available.
>
> ```
> public static final int DATA_DISCONNECTED   = 0;
> ```
>
> Data connection state: Currently setting up a data connection.
>
> ```
> public static final int DATA_CONNECTING     = 1;
> ```
>
> Data connection state: Connected. IP traffic should be available.
>
> ```
> public static final int DATA_CONNECTED      = 2;
> ```
>
> Data connection state: Suspended. The connection is up, but IP traffic is temporarily unavailable. For example, in a 2G network, data
>   activity may be suspended when a voice call arrives.
>
> ```
> public static final int DATA_SUSPENDED      = 3;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A little late to add to this post. I came to this post looking for the same result and after a while I needed to know the wifi status too. And with little more investigation ...

```
# dumpsys wifi | grep curState                                
curState=ApStaDisabledState
curState=NotConnectedState
curState=InitialState
curState=UninitializedState
curState=InitialState
```

This will give you the actual status, whether it is connected to an AccessPoint or it is still trying to connect, or if it is disabled or ...

Note: If you are planning to use the result for time critical services, you may look for other ways as waiting for a response could take a while sometimes (>5s).